# Phoenix fixture json file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I load a JSON fixture file in my phoenix project?

When I tried something like Application.app_dir(my_app, "priv"), it gives me a compiled path and I can't use that on my tests .

Is there any other way to load a fixture file from "test/support/somefile.json" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `__DIR__` with `Path.expand/2`. For example, if your tests are in `test/controllers/page_controller_test.exs`, you can get the path to `test/support/somefile.json` using:

```
path = Path.expand("../support/somefile.json", __DIR__)
```